# Flutter: General confusion about dependency injection, service locator, get_it, provider and bloc

Tags: flutter, dependency-injection, bloc, flutter-provider, service-locator

Assumptions(please check, I am probably stupid):

As far as I read, the Dependency Injection Pattern and the Service Locator Pattern, are both 2 ways to achieve Inversion of Control. The package 'get_it' facilitates the Service Locator and 'provider' the Dependency Injection. Bloc is enforcing the bloc pattern, which is a nice way to separate ui, logic and data. Bloc is using provider for Dependency injection.

Questions:

So, based on that, I don't understand why people use get_it in conjunction with bloc and/or provider. Isn't that just confusing because you are mixing patterns? There was a discussion about that with @Rémi Rousselet here: https://github.com/FilledStacks/flutter-tutorials/pull/2

Also, I can't seem to find a nice code example of a mvvm code architecture(or generally a nice separated code architecture), using provider only instead of bloc(I wanted to see if that is a nice alternative to bloc, maybe someone has a comment on that)

Comment: I wrote an [article about state management](https://medium.com/flutter-community/the-state-of-the-flutter-4a178325cced) (using provider) that might give you some insight.

Comment: There's no "real" reason.

Some folks simply enjoy doing that. A common reason is that they don't want to obtain a `BuildContext` necessary for Provider.

Comment: i use riverpod (w/ freezed and hooks), maybe you can see if it fits your use case as well. Andrea Bisotto made new tuts regarding riverpod.